# MySQL Stored Procedures: Using a result set returned from a stored procedure in another stored procedure with MYSQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

In our MySql database there are 3 stored procedures Sp1(), Sp2() and Sp3() .  There is logic in Sp3() which I want to use in the stored procedures Sp1() and Sp2(), I know that using a temporary table in Sp3() and using that temporary table  in Sp1() and Sp2() works.

To save time and memory it is preferred not to create a temporary table.

One extra piece of info is I can return a result set from a stored procedure to my client.  But I am unable to make this store procedure (SP3) work like a subquery, where the result set is returned from the Stored procedure Sp3() and can be compared with another table in Sp2() and Sp1() based on a id key.

I want to try something like below, which can be used in stored procedures Sp1() and Sp2():
Assuming Sp3() returns an id field along with other fields:

Select
    id
from
    EmployeeTable e
where 5000 >
    (Select salary from (call Sp3()) where id= e.id);

Comment: sounds like you want to use a [function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-function/) and not a stored procedure.  Factor the code in SP3 out to a Function and call the function from all 3.

Comment: @xQbert thank you, but functions only return a single value, whereas I need a result set in place of (call Sp3())